# How can I prevent a click event from firing when I call "<element>.click()"? Or what's a better way to solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(function() {
    $(".universeLink").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var link = this;

        alert(link.id);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "@Url.Action("IsUniverseCached", "Universes")" + "?universeId=" + (link.id),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success: function (returnedData) {
                if (returnedData === false) {
                    alert(returnedData);
                    $("#" + link.id).empty();
                    $("#" + link.id).html("<div class=\"alert alert-warning\"><strong>Not cached</strong> &mdash; this data will take a while to arrive!</div>");
                }

                $("#" + link.id).click();
            },

            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

I am building some JQuery to make a request before the original request is followed.

At the end of the `success` block, `$("#" + link.id).click();` is called and the event is fired again. I tried something similar with `(element).submit()` on a form, and the `.submit()` event *did not* fire again, so I assumed I could do the same trick with `.click()`.

Here's the HTML elements.

`<a id="10" href="/Universes/ViewUniverse?universeId=10&amp;regionId=8" class="universeLink">1</a>`

(the ID is dynamically assigned)

Comment: FYI, you can replace `$("#" + link.id)` with `$(link)`. You already have a reference to the element (`link`), you don't have to search for it *again*.

Comment: Thanks, I don't fully understand JavaScript/JQuery yet, so thanks for pointing my mistake out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just redirect the browser to the new location. I.e. instead of using `.click`, assign to `window.location.href`:

```
window.location.href = link.href;
```